# Реализовать функцию рекурсией

Tags: c++, рекурсия

Помогите реализовать это уравнение рекурсивной функцией:

```
(A[i-20]*(A[i-19]*(A[i-18]*...*(A[i-1]+B[i-1])+B[i-2])+B[i-3])+...+B[i-20])
```

Comment: А зачем вам тут рекурсия? Метод Горнера прекрасно кодируется итеративно, заодно вы не грузите стек. Или это учебное задание?

Comment: Пишу лабу по КМММ, это ур-ние использую для приведения матрицы к трехдиагональному виду, мне казалась что рекурсивно это ур-ние реализовать будет более лучше, а как это сделать итеративно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот итеративное решение:

```
result = 1;
for (int j = 1; j <= 20; j++)
    result = result * A[i - j] + B[i - j];
```

Рекурсия не нужна, чтобы не забивать стек понапрасну.

---

Для разминки, вот вам рекурсивное решение:

```
double GetResultRec(size_t minidx, size_t maxidx)
{
    if (minidx > maxidx) return 1.0;
    return A[minidx] * GetResultRec(minidx + 1, maxidx) + B[minidx];
}
double result = GetResultRec(i - 20, i - 1);
```

А вот рекурсивное, явно поддерживающее хвостовую рекурсию:

```
double GetResultTailRec(size_t minidx, size_t maxidx, double factor, double addend)
{
    if (minidx > maxidx) return factor + addend;
    return GetResultTailRec(
            minidx + 1, maxidx,
            factor * A[minidx],
            addend * factor + B[minidx]);
}
double result = GetResultTailRec(i - 20, i - 1, 1.0, 0.0);
```

(Есть ли более простое решение с хвостовой рекурсией?)

Comment: То есть использование рекурсии не желательно когда есть возможность сделать это итеративно, верно?

Comment: Современные компиляторы [умеют хвостовую рекурсию](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34125/which-if-any-c-compilers-do-tail-recursion-optimization), поэтому стек не забивается, если правильно писать. Но это не С++-стиль, да.

Comment: @YuraKor'evikov: Смотря от языка. Функциональные языки любят (и правильно умеют) рекурсию, там это предпочтительный вариант. Императивные языки (например, C++) лучше умеют итерацию (да им это и идеологически ближе), так что в них лучше сводить к итерации.

Comment: Есть несложная и почти самоочевидная теорема о том, что любую рекурсию можно свести к итерации (возможно, с дополнительным стеком).

Comment: @Athari: Нууууу... Надеяться на то, что компилятор умный, не стоит до тех пор, пока хвостовая рекурсия не будет **гарантирована** стандартом. Потому что условия, при которых компилятор применит tail call elimination, зависят от ключей компиляции, текущего дня недели, фазы луны, направления ветра и расстояния до Альфа Центавра. Посмотрите, например, список ситуаций, когда C# **не** применяет его: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davbr/archive/2007/06/20/tail-call-jit-conditions.aspx (это не C++, но всё же).

Comment: @Athari: Интересно, умеют ли компиляторы превращать нехвостовую рекурсию в хвостовую? Например, превратить первый рекурсивный код во второй в ответе?